# FileNotFoundException during runtime (ref to .exe file for debugging)

Tags: c#, debugging, exe, dotpeek

I've been trying to reference to custom **.exe** file to debug it.

- related .pdb file was generated with **ildasm, ilasm** utilities
- reference to executable file was added

,but in then end when debug was started i came across with **issue**:

[image]

I read that such behavior possible when some reference can't be resolved, but actually the *.exe file doesn't contains any specific refs (dotPeek screenshot):

[image]

I've encountered a lot at first sight similar questions at stackoverflow, but couldn't fined suitable for my situation

**Q:** Can anyone propose solution for the issue?

Comment: If you just reference the file then it's weird that this exception would be thrown. Could you post the full stacktrace? Also, is this file downloadable somewhere? Given the name, I guess it's part of some kind of challenge

Comment: Did you download or copied it into the Project or Output directory? My best guess would be a right issues preventing accessing it wherever you put it.

Comment: Hi, yes it is some kind of challenge task. There is no stacktrace, i try to start debug, click start and as result get above error. Actually the program ever didn't start the execution

Comment: The .exe file is the same folder where debug application running

Comment: There's always a stacktrace. When Visual Studio breaks on the exception, open the quickwatch window (shift + F9), evaluate `$exception.ToString()`, and get the result

Comment: (Also, make sure you've disabled "Just my code" in Tools -> Options -> Debugging)

Comment: After start console application state change to break mode with above error, there is not stack trace or call stack etc.

Comment: yes, i unchecked "Just my code"

Comment: What happens if you evaluate `$exception.ToString()` in a watch window when the application state change to break mode?

Comment: Ever "main" method doesn't start executing

Comment: $exception.ToString() => "Unable to execute expression" (Watch window or intermediate window)

Comment: Hm ok, I'm out of ideas. Might be some subtlety related to .net 2 runtime, or something specific to your setup. If you can upload the file somewhere I can try experimenting with it some more

Comment: Yes, without problem. Where can i share .exe file for you ?  Kevin Gosse

Comment: @Kevin Gosse 
sample file: https://files.fm/u/mmx5am5t#sign_up
Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202607/discussion-between-allmantool-and-kevin-gosse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly name is different from the file name (Assembly name is CrackMe, file name is TaskApp.exe). By renaming the file to CrackMe.exe, I'm able to reference it without errors.

To be honest, I don't know why it's a problem at all. I'm fairly certain that I've renamed assemblies in the past without any issue. I'll probably try to dig further in the coming days.

For future reference, I was able to find the issue by using fuslog (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer). With the fusion log enabled, you can clearly see that it's trying to load CrackMe.exe, even when you reference TaskApp.exe.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot for answer and explanation !